# Making a Klein bottle from 2 Möbius bands

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band

I thimk this can be done by idemtifying points on the boundary but I am not sure how to show this

Any ideas? E.g. By drawing nets..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Klein bottle is defined to be the quotient space $[0, 1]^2/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies the top and bottom by reversing orientation and the two sides by preserving orientation.

Consider the image of $[1/3, 2/3] \times [0, 1]$ and $([0, 1/3] \cup [2/3, 1]) \times [0, 1]$ under the quotient map $[0, 1]^2 \to [0, 1]^2/\sim$. These are Moebius strips, hence you obtain your decompositions.

Comment: Thanks, also can I ask why you choose the numbers 1/3 and 2/3 as the interval endpoints?

Comment: @thinker Try drawing a picture, it should be clear then.